# EF WPF - null value in column "ContractID" violates not-null constraint

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6.0.0 + Npgsql + Npgsql.EntityFramework and I'm getting following PostgreSQL error while calling `SaveChanges`:

> null value in column "ContractID" violates not-null constraint"

Here is a table I'm using in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Contracts"
(
    "ContractID" integer NOT NULL,
    "Visits" integer,
    "ClientID" integer NOT NULL,
    "Price" money,
    "SigningDate" date
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public."Contracts"
    OWNER to postgres;
```

When I try to add a row to the table, I get an exception:

[image]

My Contract class:

[image]

I tried a lot of things and I really don't understand why it happens.

Please help to understand why I'm getting this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the value of `ContactId` to `serial` rather than `integer`.As far as i see it, you are not adding any value to the column `ContactId` , so by default it's null

Hope this helps :) . If the answer doesn't help,please make sure to comment before downvoting :)

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you :)

Comment: Many thanks :) I changed integer to serial and OMG it works!